# Finding most frequent char for a given word

Tags: c#, .net, linq, aggregate, ienumerable

I want to use System.Linq  for writing a method that returns the first, most frequent character in a string.
eg: "AABABBC" => 'A'.
If two letters occur the same, the first one that appears in the string should be returned.

The sample below should work. However, I'm trying to find a more efficient solution, which doesn't imply sorting the characters first.
I was thinking of using *Enumerable.Aggregate()* for counting the repetitions while also iterating through the word. Not sure how to to that, though... 
Any ideas? Thanks :)

```
    public static char MostAparitionsChar(string word)
    {
       return word.GroupBy(x => x)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
            .Select(g => g.Key)
            .First();  
    }
```

Comment: What is *more efficient* in your case, please? Should it be faster or consume less memory?

Comment: Faster :) Instead of iterating 3 times through my string, I wanted to only iterate once

Comment: What makes you think that your code iterates through your string three times?

Comment: Question: What if all letter have the same number of occurrence? "abcd"

Comment: Is it case-insensitive match?

Comment: True enough, but then, apllying OrderByDescending and Select reiterate the projection results, which is why I don't find it very efficient. It looks to me that I should be able to directly count the repetitions, if I could somehow write my Linq expression as: word.Aggregate(0, (Function());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact implementation of OrderByDescending, but I assume it is not faster than O(n*log n). But finding a maximum value should only be O(n). Hence you can save some time if you don't sort, but only look for the maximum:

```
public static char MostAparitionsChar(string word)
 {
 char result = ' ';
 int max = int.MinValue;
 foreach(var grouping in word.GroupBy(x => x))
  {
  int count = grouping.Count();
  if(count > max)
   {
   max = count;
   result = grouping.Key;
  }
 }
 return result;
}
```

Comment: Note that this only applies to .NET Framework. .NET Core already has an optimization for `OrderBy(...).First()`